# Is it possible to do test state.apply through salt-api?

Tags: api, curl, salt-stack

Is there a way to do:

```
salt '*' state.apply nginx test=True
```

through `salt-api` ?

I'm doing this:

```
curl -sSk http://salt:8000
-H 'Accept: application/x-yaml'     
-H 'X-Auth-Token: token'    
-d client=local     
-d tgt='*'     
-d fun=state.apply    
-d arg=nginx    
-d test=True
```

but it actually applies new state.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to do `state.apply` through `salt-api` with test option.

All I needed was: `-d arg='test='true''`

Example of full request:

```
curl -sSk http://salt:8000 \ 
-H 'Accept: application/x-yaml' \    
-H 'X-Auth-Token: token' \ 
-d client=local \ 
-d tgt='*' \ 
-d fun='state.apply' \ 
-d arg='nginx' \ 
-d arg='test='true''
```

Answer (score 0):

what about `curl -sSk http://salt:8000/run` instead of `curl -sSk http://salt:8000`

and are you using `\` at the end of each option?

otherwise it looks good, what version of salt are you running?

https://salt-sproxy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/salt_api.html <= good reading